# Squeeze Principle and Sin x

Tags: limits

How does the Squeeze Principle used to find that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sin x / x$? I understand what the squeeze principle is, but do not understand how to use it for this example.

Comment: Hint: $-1/x \leqslant \sin x / x \leqslant 1/ x$ Now take limits as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the basic fact that $-1\leq \sin x\leq1,$ we get $$-\frac{1}{x}\leq \frac{\sin x}{x}\leq\frac{1}{x}.$$ Now apply Squeeze theorem.